# Adding gps coordinate to image in angular and uploading and extracting coordinate

Tags: image, gps

Hi  looking for Adding gps coordinate to image in angular and uploading and extracting coordinate. Is it possible ? any library open source ?

Comment: You mean like google map, or like mapbox? What are you trying to acheive is unclear

Comment: I need  an image which have coordinate attached to it when i capture and  can upload any time i want

Comment: You want to store coordinates into a jpg file for example?

Comment: MathieuAuclair yes

Answer (score 0):

Following this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53515567/please-recommend-a-node-module-for-writing-iptc-data-to-images), you may use the node package exiftool. With this package you can add meta data to a picture using tags. You can then read those tags on a picture and check if they are defined. That way the coordinates are directly store onto the picture file itself.

Comment: Thank you MathieuAuclair i will definately try this